# Logstash persistent queue files changes owner to root and gets inaccessible by java

Tags: java, ruby, ubuntu, logstash, elk

I have just updated my ELK-Stack to 7.9.1 from 7.0.1 (using apt)
System: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Besides some permission issues I won't get into here there seems to be a problem with permissions for my persistent queue tail files.
as the page.nnn file is updated it gets owned by root which causes java to fail.

Steps to reproduce:

1. change owner for pipeline tail file folder to logstash.

```
   /data/logstash/data/queue/my_pipeline$ ls -l
   total 47016  
   -rw-r--r-- 1 logstash logstash       34 Oct 21 08:56 checkpoint.head
   -rw-r--r-- 1 logstash logstash 67108864 Oct 21 08:56 page.868
```

2. Push data to Logstash using FileBeat
3. Check owner of files

```
        /data/logstash/data/queue/my_pipeline$ ls -l
        total 8
       -rw-r--r-- 1 root root       34 Oct 21 09:12 checkpoint.head
       -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 67108864 Oct 21 09:12 page.869
```

The error:

```
/data/logstash/data/queue/my_pipeline$ sudo journalctl -e --unit=logstash | grep FileNotFoundException | tail -1
Oct 21 09:29:06 my_server.my_domain.com logstash[38158]: [2020-10-21T09:29:06,496][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] 
Failed to execute action {
:action => LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:my_pipeline, :exception => "Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException", 
:message => "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/logstash/data/queue/my_pipeline/page.869 (Permission denied)", 
:backtrace => ["org.logstash.execution.AbstractPipelineExt.openQueue(AbstractPipelineExt.java:204)",
"org.logstash.execution.AbstractPipelineExt$INVOKER$i$0$0$openQueue.call(AbstractPipelineExt$INVOKER$i$0$0$openQueue.gen)", 
"org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodN.call(JavaMethod.java:831)", 
"org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207)", 
"usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$method$initialize$0(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:45)", 
"org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:80)", 
"org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:70)", 
"org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:332)", 
"org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:86)", 
"org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:939)", 
"org.jruby.RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen)", 
"org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207)", 
"usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline_action.create.RUBY$method$execute$0(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:52)", 
"usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline_action.create.RUBY$method$execute$0$__VARARGS__(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb)", 
"org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:80)", 
"org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:70)", 
"org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207)", 
"usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.agent.RUBY$block$converge_state$2(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:357)", 
"org.jruby.runtime.CompiledIRBlockBody.callDirect(CompiledIRBlockBody.java:138)", 
"org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:58)", 
"org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:52)",
"org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:139)", "org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:318)", 
"org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:105)", 
"java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)"]
}
```

I have sourced through config-files for Logstash without being able to find any settings for this. My suspicion is that it's related to my JRE, but as I am not proficient enough I am not able to find the reason for this.

tl;dr: How to make Logstash persistent queue tail files owned by logstash permanently?

Comment: what is the user you are using for starting logstash?

Comment: Logstash is started as a service either at system start or by running systemctl start logstash.service
From logstash.service: 
[Service]
Type=simple
User=logstash
Group=logstash

Comment: Will you be able to add output for `ps -ef | grep logstash`